# Does a simple `return` in a PHP function simply end the function prematurely?

Tags: php, function

I have just seen this

```
// Check to see if the request is a XHR call    
if (request::is_ajax())
{
  // Send the 403 header
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
  return;
}
```

I have not seen a simple `return` before, and I have never used it. My only guess is that it simply acts the same as any `return 'something'` (halting the function), except doesn't actually return a result.

Furthermore, what would happen in this situation?

```
function text($var)   
{
    if ( ! $var) {
        return;
    }
    do_something();
}

$var = text('');
```

I know it's a bad example (it should probably return false or throw an exception), but would it be an error, or would the `$var` simply be null or blank?

Comment: I think you meant XHR, not HXR :)

Comment: @Gab - that was just an example I found on the net.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
function text($var) 

{

    if ( ! $var) {
        return;
    }
    do_something();

}

$var = text('');

echo gettype($var);
echo is_bool($var) ? "true" : "false";
echo is_string($var) ? "true" : "false";
echo is_null($var) ? "true" : "false";
```

returns:

NULL
false
false
true

Answer (score 9):

PHP is dynamically typed, so returning no value is equivalent to returning a null value in any type.

Answer (score 7):

A return with no value returns null.

More information from the manual:

> If called from within a function, the return()  statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call. return() will also end the execution
>   of an eval() statement or script file.
>
> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script
>   file is ended. If the current script file was include()ed or
>   require()ed, then control is passed back to the calling file.
>   Furthermore, if the current script file was include()ed, then the
>   value given to return() will be returned as the value of the include()
>   call. If return() is called from within the main script file, then
>   script execution ends. If the current script file was named by the
>   auto_prepend_file or auto_append_file configuration options in
>   php.ini, then that script file's execution is ended.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, "[return;](http://php.net/return)" or return(); in a function stops running that function (or file if the return statement is not in a function) at that point (if the code is executed) and technically returns a null value.

Your first example would output the 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden' header and then end that function if request::is_ajax() equals true.

In your code example:

```
function text($var) 
{

    if ( ! $var) {
        return;
    }
    do_something();

}
$var = text('');
```

You can have the following out comes:

- If $var is NOT TRUE (i.e. false, null, text or an integer), then exit function and return null.
- If $var is EXACTLY TRUE (the if statement is checking if $var is anything but true), then run do_something();

I would suspect you probably want to change the if statement to either:

```
if (!is_string($var)) {
```

if you just want to do_something() to a string or

```
if (is_null($var)) {
```

if you only want to do_something() to $var if it's been set. You may also want to change your function declaration to:
function text($var==NULL) {
so if you call text without a paramter, $var is automatically set to null.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer. It just ends the function, its much like a function with no return statement. Nothing is returned, the function is just exited.

In your second example, $var would = nothing.

Why not execute it and see?

Comment: I wanted to get some response from the community and hopefully some advice. Thanks for your answer.