# What happens if I don't include a "return" at the end of a function in PHP?

Tags: php

I've seen lots of instances when a "return" is included at the end of function in PHP yet passes no value and therefore would return null. I know it also exits the function, but is that necessary or is the return superfluous/just a way for developers to communicate that the function doesn't return any value?

A code example:

```
// Check to see if the request is a HXR call

if (request::is_ajax())
{
  // Send the 403 header
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
  return;
}
```

See? Couldn't you take out the `return;` and have exactly the same functionality? Or, if there were other functions following this if statement, would they not run because the computer would be stuck in the if statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a simple \`return\` in a PHP function simply end the function prematurely?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113912/does-a-simple-return-in-a-php-function-simply-end-the-function-prematurely)

Comment: It depends if something else would run if you didn't `return` (or, as the case may be, `exit`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. You do not need the return statement. It is only necessary when returning information out of the function, or to stop execution of the function. Otherwise the function will stop when it goes out of scope (reaches the closing bracket).

Answer (score 1):

Developers use `return` to declare the end of the function so even when there is code after the `return` it will not be executed and it will be escaped. And it's not obligatory.